# Broke outdoor spigot from its pipe, discovered pipe is PVC instead of metal. How to repair this?

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, spigot

This spigot comes out of my walkout basement wall outside (with plastic sidings). It had this stupid anti-siphoning attachment that restricted water flow, so I tried to twist that off and broke the pipe behind the spigot. Surprise! The pipe the spigot is on is a small PVC pipe.

The pipe goes through about 30 feet of walls. Would I need to rip those walls out to repair this? Or do I only need to remove the siding outside and "glue" or "fuse" things back somehow?

[image]
[image]

Comment: you should not have PVC inside the house because of flooding concerns .... replace the pipe with something suitable

Comment: What is on the other side of that wall? Normally, you would cut it on the inside with plenty of room to work, replace the faucet, and replace the missing length of pipe

Comment: Unhandledexceptscean, make that an answer, pvc on cold water pipe is fine inside a house , many times opening the wall inside is required to access pipes and repair.